# regex to find all words after specific word?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

I have a string like below:

```
Features:  -Includes hanging accessories.  -Artist: William-Adolphe Bouguereau.  -Made with 100pct cotton canvas.  -100pct Anti-shrink pine wood bars and Epson anti-fade ultra chrome inks.  -100pct Hand-made and inspected in the U.S.A.  -Orientation: Horizontal.  **Subject: -Figures/Nautical and beach.**  Gender: -Unisex/Both.  Size: -Mini 17'' and under/Small 18''-24''/Medium 25''-32''/Large 33''-40''/Oversized 41'' and above.  Style: -Fine art.  Color: -Blue.  Country of Manufacture: -United States.  Product Type: -Print of painting.  Region: -Europe.  Primary Art Material: -Canvas. Dimensions:  -8'' H x 12'' W x 0.75'' D: 0.72 lb.  -12'' H x 18'' W x 0.75'' D: 1.14 lbs.  -12'' H x 18'' W x 1.5'' D: 2.45 lbs.  -18'' H x 26'' W x 0.75'' D: 1.44 lbs.  Paintings Prints Tori White Wildon Photography Photos Posters Abstract Black D cor Designs Framed Hazelwood Hokku Home Landscape Oil Accent 075 12 15 18 26 40 60 8 D H W x 1 1017 1824 2532 holidays, christmas gift gifts for girls boys
```

I have to find the words after particular word.

I want to extract the words after the word `"Subject"` in above example.

The output should be like below:

```
Subject: -Figures/Nautical and beach.
```

I tried below regex:

```
re.compile('(?<=subject)(.{30}(?:\s|.))',re.I)
```

But there is not fixed number of words after subject keyword to specify so I can't specify exact number of words.

How do I stop at "peroid" or space.There is no specific stopping criterion.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just split on `**` and index the resulting list? `s.split("**")[1]` yields exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: If your problem isn't really well-defined, the answers are going to be hit and miss as well.  The regex for "period or space" is `[\s.]` but that is obviously not by itself the solution to your problem.  Think harder about what you actually need.

Comment: A lot of the answers are about the asterisks, which apparently you put in simply to highlight the field you want to extract.  Perhaps you should take them out, so that your example input is *precisely* an example of what you actually need to handle.  I don't think anybody can misunderstand the phrase "extract the `Subject:` value" anyway (though it's not clear how to decide where it ends).

Answer (score 2):

Your `(?<=subject)(.{30}(?:\s|.))` regex asserts the position after `subject`. then grabs 30 characters other than a linebreak symbol and then matches either a whitespace or any character but a linebreak symbol. This does not really fit your requirements as the substring can be of any length.

You may use alternation based regex with a capturing group:

```
subject:\s*([^.]+|\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aC3pC1/1)

**Details**:

- `subject:` - literal `subject:` string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^.]+|\S+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more non-period symbols or 1+ non-whitespace symbols

**Note**: the order of the alternatives *matters* here since `[^.]+` matches spaces, and `\S+` does not. If the substring after `\s*` starts with a dot, the `\S+` will match that substring up to a whitespace.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/JRe3y9):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'subject:\s*([^.]+|\S+)', re.IGNORECASE)
s = "Features:  -Includes hanging accessories.  -Artist: William-Adolphe Bouguereau.  -Made with 100pct cotton canvas.  -100pct Anti-shrink pine wood bars and Epson anti-fade ultra chrome inks.  -100pct Hand-made and inspected in the U.S.A.  -Orientation: Horizontal.  **Subject: -Figures/Nautical and beach.**  Gender: -Unisex/Both.  Size: -Mini 17'' and under/Small 18''-24''/Medium 25''-32''/Large 33''-40''/Oversized 41'' and above.  Style: -Fine art.  Color: -Blue.  Country of Manufacture: -United States.  Product Type: -Print of painting.  Region: -Europe.  Primary Art Material: -Canvas. Dimensions:  -8'' H x 12'' W x 0.75'' D: 0.72 lb.  -12'' H x 18'' W x 0.75'' D: 1.14 lbs.  -12'' H x 18'' W x 1.5'' D: 2.45 lbs.  -18'' H x 26'' W x 0.75'' D: 1.44 lbs.  Paintings Prints Tori White Wildon Photography Photos Posters Abstract Black D cor Designs Framed Hazelwood Hokku Home Landscape Oil Accent 075 12 15 18 26 40 60 8 D H W x 1 1017 1824 2532 holidays, christmas gift gifts for girls boys"
m = p.search(s)
if m:
    print(m.group())    # this includes Subject: 
    print(m.group(1))   # this does not include Subject:
```

Comment: its giving the output correctly. I was wondering it doesn't stop at 'whitespace' because some times there is no period or any other non-word character.

Comment: I also added a Note now explaining why `\S+` is necessary. The `[^.]` matches any char (incl. a space) and `+` makes it match one or more times greedily.

Comment: consider this string                                                                                       " Sports and sports teams</li><li>Gender: Neutral</li><li>Style: Contemporary</li><li>Medium: Giclee printed</li><li>Product Type: Graphic art</li><li>Primary Art Material: Canvas</li> <br /><strong>Dimensions</strong><br />Size 36'' H x 24'' W x 1.5''

Comment: There is no "Subject:" in this string you provided in the comment.

Comment: sorry.  " Subject: Sports and sports teams</li><li>Gender: Neutral</li><li>Style: Contemporary</li><li>Medium: Giclee printed</li><li>Product Type: Graphic art</li><li>Primary Art Material: Canvas</li> <br /><strong>Dimensions</strong><br />Size 36'' H x 24'' W x 1.5'

Comment: That is HTML, and you need to use BeautifulSoup to parse it correctly. Actually, I do not understand what the expected output for it is. Try https://regex101.com/r/aC3pC1/2

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
re.compile('Subject: [^*]+')
```

[Demo](http://pythex.org/?regex=Subject%3A%20%5B%5E%5C*%5D%2B&test_string=Features%3A%20%20-Includes%20hanging%20accessories.%20%20-Artist%3A%20William-Adolphe%20Bouguereau.%20%20-Made%20with%20100pct%20cotton%20canvas.%20%20-100pct%20Anti-shrink%20pine%20wood%20bars%20and%20Epson%20anti-fade%20ultra%20chrome%20inks.%20%20-100pct%20Hand-made%20and%20inspected%20in%20the%20U.S.A.%20%20-Orientation%3A%20Horizontal.%20%20**Subject%3A%20-Figures%2FNautical%20and%20beach.**%20%20Gender%3A%20-Unisex%2FBoth.%20%20Size%3A%20-Mini%2017%27%27%20and%20under%2FSmall%2018%27%27-24%27%27%2FMedium%2025%27%27-32%27%27%2FLarge%2033%27%27-40%27%27%2FOversized%2041%27%27%20and%20above.%20%20Style%3A%20-Fine%20art.%20%20Color%3A%20-Blue.%20%20Country%20of%20Manufacture%3A%20-United%20States.%20%20Product%20Type%3A%20-Print%20of%20painting.%20%20Region%3A%20-Europe.%20%20Primary%20Art%20Material%3A%20-Canvas.%20Dimensions%3A%20%20-8%27%27%20H%20x%2012%27%27%20W%20x%200.75%27%27%20D%3A%200.72%20lb.%20%20-12%27%27%20H%20x%2018%27%27%20W%20x%200.75%27%27%20D%3A%201.14%20lbs.%20%20-12%27%27%20H%20x%2018%27%27%20W%20x%201.5%27%27%20D%3A%202.45%20lbs.%20%20-18%27%27%20H%20x%2026%27%27%20W%20x%200.75%27%27%20D%3A%201.44%20lbs.%20%20Paintings%20Prints%20Tori%20White%20Wildon%20Photography%20Photos%20Posters%20Abstract%20Black%20D%20cor%20Designs%20Framed%20Hazelwood%20Hokku%20Home%20Landscape%20Oil%20Accent%20075%2012%2015%2018%2026%2040%2060%208%20D%20H%20W%20x%201%201017%201824%202532%20holidays%2C%20christmas%20gift%20gifts%20for%20girls%20boys&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: Note you do not need to escape `*` inside a character class, as the `*` inside `[...]` loses its original meaning of a quantifier.

Comment: That `{2}` makes `[^*{2}]+` pattern mean: 1 or more characters other than `*`, `{`, `2` and `}`. Actually, it seems this asterisk after the expected value might be missing in the input. I deduce it from OP comments to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex:**

```
(Subject:.+)\*\*

Match Subject and content after that till '**'
```

**Code:**

```
str = 'Features:  -Includes hanging accessories.  -Artist: William-Adolphe Bouguereau.  -Made with 100pct cotton canvas.  -100pct Anti-shrink pine wood bars and Epson anti-fade ultra chrome inks.  -100pct Hand-made and inspected in the U.S.A.  -Orientation: Horizontal.  **Subject: -Figures/Nautical and beach.**  Gender: -Unisex/Both.  Size: -Mini 17'' and under/Small 18''-24''/Medium 25''-32''/Large 33''-40''/Oversized 41'' and above.  Style: -Fine art.  Color: -Blue.  Country of Manufacture: -United States.  Product Type: -Print of painting.  Region: -Europe.  Primary Art Material: -Canvas. Dimensions:  -8'' H x 12'' W x 0.75'' D: 0.72 lb.  -12'' H x 18'' W x 0.75'' D: 1.14 lbs.  -12'' H x 18'' W x 1.5'' D: 2.45 lbs.  -18'' H x 26'' W x 0.75'' D: 1.44 lbs.  Paintings Prints Tori White Wildon Photography Photos Posters Abstract Black D cor Designs Framed Hazelwood Hokku Home Landscape Oil Accent 075 12 15 18 26 40 60 8 D H W x 1 1017 1824 2532 holidays, christmas gift gifts for girls boys'
import re

a = re.search(r'(Subject:.+)\*\*',str)
print(a.group(1))
```

Comment: Actually, it seems this asterisk after the expected value might be missing in the input. I deduce it from OP comments to my answer.